# How to get listbox id inside the listview in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to to get listbox id inside the listview in javascript.

This is my Javascript:

```
<script>

             Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(
      function (sender, e) {
          var control = $find('<%= results.ClientID %>');
          if (e.get_postBackElement().id =="<%=this.results.ClientID%>") {
               $get("divvv").style.display = "none";
           }
           else {
               $get("divvv").style.display = "block";
           }
 });

</script>
```

results is my listbox id but it is in the listview so that i couldn't get the listbox it directly as specified above.It shows Error.
Please hel me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i havent tested but you can try this

```
function (sender, e) {
          var control = $find('<%= ((ListBox)MyListView.FindControl("myListBox")).ClientID %>');
          if (e.get_postBackElement().id =='<%= ((ListBox)MyListView.FindControl("myListBox")).ClientID %>') {
               $get("divvv").style.display = "none";
           }
           else {
               $get("divvv").style.display = "block";
           }
```

Comment: Hello Arda I changed as you said but the exception was thrown like Object reference not set to an instance of an object.